# Criar barra de pesquisa

Tags: html

Estou criando um site e desenhei a barra de pesquisa. O problema é que não sei ativar ela ou seja que funcione com o meu site em html. Há uma maneira fácil usando as caixas de pesquisas do google no nosso site mas o design que desenhei para a barra de pesquisa é diferente das da google. Alguém ajuda?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ignorem os dois riscos verticais azuis. Quero criar esta barra de pesquisa só não sei criar e depois que ela funcione.

Comment: Tem que ser mais especifico, se possível postar umas prints, o código e descrever o o que você espera fazer, o resultado a ser obtido, e sem se preocupar em como você vai chegar até ele, porque nisso a gente pode te ajudar.

Comment: O site é completamente em HTML? Creio que para criar um sistema de busca, você precisará aprimorar o backend do seu site, ou seja, usar PHP/ASP/ASP.Net...

Answer (score 4):

Para usar sua própria caixa de pesquisa na pesquisa personalizada do Google, você deve criar um [mecanismo de pesquisa personalizada](https://cse.google.com.br/cse/lookandfeel/layout?). Vá em "aparência" e selecione a aba "layout". [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Escolha a opção "somente resultados" e depois clique em "salvar e obter código" Você vai ser levado para uma página onde está o código que você deve colar no fonte da página onde você quer que apareçam os resultados no seu site. Existe um botão "Especificar detalhes dos resultados da pesquisa". Clicando nesse botão, vai haver um campo com o parâmetro para passar a consulta para a pesquisa, que por padrão é "q". Esse parâmetro deve ser igual ao valor do atributo "name" do campo de texto da sua caixa de pesquisa. O atributo "action" do formulário da sua caixa de pesquisa deve ser igual ao endereço da página onde você que que a pesquisa apareça, ou seja, onde você colou o código anteriormente citado.

```html
<form method="post" action="pagina_de_resultados.html">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="Pesquisar...">
  <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```

Comment: Eu sei fazer isso com o google. Veja o design que fiz da caixa. Penso que não dá para aplicar esse design a uma caixa de pesquisa da google. Agradeço a sua ajuda mesmo que não tenha sido o que pretendia (até ao momento) será certamente útil para muita gente que não conheçe como adicionar caixa de pesquisa da google.

Comment: talvez se usar CSS, você consiga alterar o layout da barra de pesquisas do google